# SQL Server - Select daily values for each month

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a Table in SQL server that looks like this:

```
Machine        Time                  Parts

  A            2018-12-11 00:00      12
  A            2018-12-11 01:00      38
  A            2018-12-11 02:00      52
                    .....
  A            2018-12-11 23:00      13
  A            2018-12-12 00:00      45
  A            2018-12-12 01:00      35
                    .....
  A            2019-01-10 22:00      25
  A            2019-01-10 23:00      68
  A            2019-01-11 00:00      29
  A            2019-01-11 01:00      36
  A            2019-01-11 02:00      19
  A            2019-01-11 03:00      52
                    .....
```

The number of parts the machine produces is stored in the table on a hourly basis. 
What I need is a query that takes all the data let's say between December 11th 2018 00:00 and January 11th 2019 00:00, calculates the sum of parts of each day and returns all the 31 sum values.

I have been trying to solve this for a couple of days but have been unable to do so since my SQL skills are still weak. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please add your query trial

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you just looking to get the date from `time`?

```
select cast(time as date) as dte, sum(parts)
from t
where time >= '2018-12-11' and time < '2019-01-11'
group by cast(time as date)
order by cast(time as date);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I will try that and the answers in the suggested similar question as soon as I get back to my work computer.
I need the query for a Stored Procedure which I will use in a c# application. In the application there is a graph which is populated with the values of the Parts table. There are also two DateTime pickers which allows the user to pick the dates between which the values will be shown. I need the query I am asking for in case the user wants to see the values of 1 month, in this case I want to show the daily total of parts instead of hundreds of hourly values.